# Regex capture all words in a line before the last 2

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-negation

I have a bunch of line data I need to capture like so:

```
Level production data TD Index
Total Agriculture\Production data TS Index
```

I need to capture everything before the last two words, for example in this case my regex output should be `Level production data` for the first match.  How can I do this while also assuming varying number of words before the `TD Index`. Thanks!

Comment: can you show an effort you made to solve this yourself and why it didn't work

Comment: You can use: [`^.*(?=(?:\s+\w+){2}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/MsyP5c/3)

Comment: `.*(?= \S+ \S+)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

`^.*(?=(?:\s+\S+){2}$)`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cm7w7Z/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline character
- `(?=(?:\s+\S+){2}$)` - positive lookahead to validate that current position is followed by 2 words (1+ white space followed by 1+ occurrences of non-whitespace)X2 just before the end of the string

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to make this so I don't need to use the multiline flag?

Comment: Try this: [`.*(?=(?:\s+\S+){2}(?:\n|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/cm7w7Z/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = ["Level production data TD Index", "Total Agriculture\Production data TS Index"]
new_s = [re.findall('[\w\s\W]{1,}(?=\s\w+\s\w+$)', i)[0] for i in s]
```

Output:

```
['Level production data', 'Total Agriculture\\Production data']
```

Answer (score 0):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/0B3eNZ/3)

```
.*(?= \S+ \S+)
```

Alternatively: `.*(?= [\w\/]+ [\w\/]+)` replacing `\S` with what you define as your valid word character set.

You can also add `+` after the spaces if there is a possibility of more than 1 space being present as such: `.*(?= +\S+ +\S+)`

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/beycyx)

```
import re

r = r".*(?= \S+ \S+)"

l = [
    "Level production data TD Index",
    "Total Agriculture\\Production data TS Index"
]

for s in l:
    m = re.match(r, s)
    if m:
        print m.group(0)
```

---

### Explanation

- `.*` Match any character any number of times
- `(?= \S+ \S+)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

  - Match a literal space
  - `\S+` Match any non-whitespace character one or more times
  - Match a literal space
  - `\S+` Match any non-whitespace character one or more times